# How add two button to scroller in fragment

Tags: java, android

i have DetailsFragment class, this class add two button to "fragment" xml , but when i add two buttons to "scroller", the program show me expiation "ScrollView can host only one direct child".
please help me hoe add two button to "scroller"  in java code.

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (container == null) {
                return null;
            }
     LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.t);
            ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
            Button m =new  Button(getActivity());
            m.setText("adfgadgfdsfg");
            m.setWidth(100);
            m.setHeight(30);
            m.setTextSize(30);
           scroller.addView(m);

     //*** expiation in this code but when i clear m1 code is work   
            Button m1 =new  Button(getActivity());
            m1.setText("adfgadgfdsfg");
            m1.setWidth(100);
            m1.setHeight(30);
            m1.setTextSize(30);
           scroller.addView(m1);


        }
    }
```

code xml layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@color/color_detial_fragment" 

             />
           <LinearLayout 
           android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          ></LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you error states:

```
ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

So what you should do is to create a layout (`LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout`) place in inside the `ScrollView`, and place your buttons inside this layout. Like this:

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayout);
 Button m =new  Button(getActivity());
 m.setText("adfgadgfdsfg");
 m.setWidth(100);
 m.setHeight(30);
 m.setTextSize(30);
 ll.addView(m); 

 Button m1 =new  Button(getActivity());
 m1.setText("adfgadgfdsfg");
 m1.setWidth(100);
 m1.setHeight(30);
 m1.setTextSize(30);
 ll.addView(m1);

 scroller.addView(ll);
```

Comment: when i add LinearLayout have id "t" inside FrameLayout in xml and add to java file line: LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.t); Error in findViewById

Comment: Error in LinearLayout linearLayout(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.t);

Comment: Is the layout you have posted is your fragment's layout? if yes then you trying to add a fragment inside a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

We can't add two childs to scrollview, it allows only one child. Create one linear layout and add buttons to that layout , and then add this layout to scroll view .

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
Button btn = new Button(this); 
btn.setText("MyButton"); 
linearLayout.addView(btn); 

Button btn2 = new Button(this); 
btn2.setText("MyButton"); 
linearLayout.addView(btn2); 

scrollview.addView(linearLayout);
```

Comment: when i add LinearLayout have id "t" inside FrameLayout in xml  and add to java file line: LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.t); Error in findViewById